# How can I access the contents of nested environments in the definition of the parent environment?

Tags: environments

I would like to have an environment that contains three subenvironments, like so:

```
\begin{Outer}
    \begin{InnerA}
        Content A.
    \end{InnerA}
    \begin{InnerB}
        Content B.
    \end{InnerB}
    \begin{InnerC}
        Content C.
    \end{InnerC}
\end{Outer}
```

How can I access the content of the inner environments in the definition for the Outer environment? For example, I may wish the Outer environment to display the contents of the inner environments in a particular order, with distinct formatting.

Comment: define `Outer` with \NewDocumentEnvironment `b` argument then you have body of the macro as `#1` and you can locally define the inner environments to do whatever you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is an elementary implementation of what you might be after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{Outer}{ }{%
  % Ensure that inner body macros are defined.
  \def\InnerABody{}%
  \def\InnerBBody{}%
  \def\InnerCBody{}%
}{%
  % Format/re-order inner bodies.
  {\color{red}\bfseries\InnerABody\par}%
  {\color{blue}\large\InnerCBody\par}%
  {\color{green}\ttfamily\InnerBBody\par}%
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{InnerA}{ b }{}{%
  \gdef\InnerABody{#1}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{InnerB}{ b }{}{%
  \gdef\InnerBBody{#1}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{InnerC}{ b }{}{%
  \gdef\InnerCBody{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Outer}
  \begin{InnerA}
    Content A.
  \end{InnerA}
  \begin{InnerB}
    Content B.
  \end{InnerB}
  \begin{InnerC}
    Content C.
  \end{InnerC}
\end{Outer}

\end{document}
```

The idea is to capture the contents of `InnerA`, `InnerB` and `InnerC` environments in macros `\InnerABody`, `\InnerBBody` and `\InnerCBody`, respectively. Then, at the closing of `Outer` (as part of `\end{Outer}`), you can format and/or change the order in which the respective inner environment bodies are displayed.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks very much!